# How to implement AppFabric Cache using WF and WCF

Tags: appfabric

I am new to Windows Server AppFabric Cache.
Does anyone know how to implement AppFabric cache using AppFabric hosting services and caching services with help of WF and WCF...? 
Or is there any good and simple tutorial/ebooks for AppFabric implementation.....? 
What is difference between AppFabric hosting and caching services..? 
Our requirement is to convert an existing asp.net cache to AppFabric cache in order to reduce DB read/write overhead.
 Can we achieve this with limited code change...?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to AppFabric product documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351389.aspx

Hey, have you also looked into NCache for your caching needs? [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/nache/) is a very feature rich

distributed caching solution for .NET applications and much more powerful than

AppFabric, especially in your case when you want to reduce the database overhead. Whereas, AppFabric has limited set of topologies (architectures), Ncache provides numerous topologies according to your application needs in terms of high-availability and fault-tolerance

I know that NCache provides all of ASP.NET Cache features like Cache Dependency and

SqlDependency which AppFabric does not.